# Fluent syntax and inheritance

Tags: java, android, inheritance

I want to inherit a method from a base class with fluent syntax:

```
class BaseModel {
      int count;

      public BaseModel setCount(int value){
           this.count=value;
           return this;
      }
}


class FooModel extends BaseModel{
      int age;

      public FooModel setAge(int value){
           this.age=value;
           return this;
      }
}
```

The problem with this code is that the line:

```
FooModel model= new FooModel().setCount(2).setAge(25);
```

Makes the compiler complain because the `setCount` method return type is `BaseModel` instead of `FooModel`.

Is there some way of declare the method in the parent in order to the subclasses return the correct type without manually overriding the method in every child class?

```
class FooModel extends BaseModel{
      int age;

      public FooModel setAge(int value){
           this.age=value;
           return this;
      }

      @Override
      public FooModel setCount(int value){
           super.setCount(value);
           return this;
      }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I would say generics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the only way I see is to use generics:

```
class BaseModel<T> {
    int count;

    public T setCount(int value) {
        this.count = value;
        return (T) this;
    }
}

class FooModel extends BaseModel<FooModel> {
    int age;

    public FooModel setAge(int value) {
        this.age = value;
        return this;
    }
}
```

With this, you can write your desired code-snippet

```
FooModel model = new FooModel().setCount(2).setAge(25);
```

Comment: this way you could have `class FooModel extends BaseModel<Integer>` which is valid, but it doesn't accomplish what the op asked

Comment: @Blackbelt Indeed. Did not consider this.

Answer (score 1):

I would use generics, bounding `BaseModel` to `T extends BaseModel<T>`

```
class BaseModel<T extends BaseModel<T>> {
```

this way your type `T` will still have to derive from `BaseModel`